# generating insert,update delete code in database table zend framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

i'm writing a lot of code in ZEND framework 2 in insert , delete and update queries

is there a way to generate code automatically ?

for example i had a table named **Album** contain

```
id 
artist 
title
```

now i have to write code for adding , editing and deleting albums

**Is there a way to automate the process  ?**

Comment: How were you doing it for Zend Framework 1.X ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing the queries by hand you can use [`Zend\Db\TableGateway`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/modules/zend.db.table-gateway.html).

```
$table = new TableGateway("Album", $adapter);
$table->insert(array('artist' => "...", 'title' => "..."));
```

There is a more complete example that covers also updating and deleting rows in the [official 'Getting Started' tutorial](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/user-guide/database-and-models.html).

Comment: you did not understand me actually i'm using TableGateway i mean something that can generate controller , model and view for any table automatically for me